# What is the longest sequence of vowels in one word that you know of?

Tags: orthography, written-language, vowels

What are the longest sequence of vowels in a natural language that you know of? Be aware that this is an orthographic question, not a phonetical.

Please state word, language and translation.

Comment: How do you define an "orthographic vowel"?

Comment: Good question... Vowels in writing. Probably would depend on the language. Is the language using that specific letter regarding that as a vowel? I think semi-vowels will be troublesome... Do you have any examples of words where this problem arises?

Comment: Well I was wondering about the letter _y_ in your own examples from Norwegian below. I don't know too much about Norwegian, but I don't think the sound represented by _y_ is syllabic, phonologically speaking, so I'm not sure I'd count it as representing a vowel.

Comment: Yes, in the examples I gave from Norwegian it is a semi-vowel, pronounced as j. But y is still ortographically a vowel in Norwegian.

Comment: And do transliterations count? I'm not sure I'd equate a transliteration system with an orthography (though in the case of @fdb's answer the transliteration is actually representing the native orthography). Or what about alternative digraphs of characters, like _oe_ for ö in German, for example? Would that count as "two letters"?

Comment: This is a list question which makes it too broad.

Comment: I am not interested in a list, only the longest sequence of vowels

Comment: @musicallinguist No transliterations, only words written in standard ortography of a certain language

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a trivia question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hooiaioia** in Hawaiian (meaning *certified*), with 8 vowels, seems to have the most consecutive vowels in current human speech. It is also listed in 1976 Guinness Book of World Records.

Comment: What is the exact name for the Guiness world record?

Comment: @Flying Do you mean which record it set? It's probably about the vowels, but I don't know where to search for that properly to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Avestan āuuōiia “woe!” has seven (orthographic) vowels in succession.

Avestan kāuuaiiasca “and evil rulers” has eight.

(In both cases this is a one-to-one transliteration of the Avestan script, which is unfortunately not available in Unicode.)

Answer (score 0):

6 vowels. Saueøye (sheep eye, in Norwegian. This is a real life example)

9 vowels. Saueøyeeier (the owner of the sheep eye, a constructed word)

7 vowels. Niøyeøye (the eye of a fish called Niøye, not very common word, but possible)

12 vowels. Niøyeøyeøyeier (the owner of an island named after the eye of a fish called Niøye, this is a constructed word, but still understandable)